# Destructuring Assignment with objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to unpack values from an array of objects using destructuring assigments?

```
[

{a : 1},
{a : 1},
{a : 1},
{a : 1}

]
```

The result I need here is an array:  [1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring that would require the creation of 4 separate variables which would then get recombined into an array later. It would be very WET, and wouldn't make much sense, but if you *had* to:

```js
const arr = [
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1}
]
const [{ a: item1 }, { a: item2 }, {a: item3}, {a: item4 }] = arr;
const newArrOfAs = [item1, item2, item3, item4];
console.log(newArrOfAs);
```

Your original code using `reduce` is better, but even more appropriate would be to use `Array.prototype.map`, since the input array and output array's items are one-to-one:

```js
const arr = [
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1}
]
const newArrOfAs = arr.map(({ a }) => a);
console.log(newArrOfAs);
```

Comment: seems like that makes no sense if the array is longer than that. I think array.map is then the best solution. Really thought of using reduce combined with this {} but was just a pseudo code idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would use `.map()`:

```js
const a = [

  {
    a: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1
  }

];


const b = a.map(val => val.a);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can use foreach or map

```js
const array = [
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1},
  {a : 1}
]
let newArray = []
array.forEach(function(element) {
  newArray.push(element.a)
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `map`:

```js
 

const arr = [
{a : 1},
{a : 1},
{a : 1},
{a : 1}
];

const res = arr.map(({ a }) => a);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
var array = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1 }];
    result = array.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```